# Pyscript displaying chart from matplotlib

Tags: python, html, file, display, pyscript

In HTML i have a button which call a pi function (myplots) in a file which name is my_plot.py.
All work without error and when i click the button the function is called and goes at the end.
The problem is nothing is displayed.
Same code but with inline function work perfecly.

My html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
-->    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <script src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/glassfish/essai_pyscript/fonction.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
<title>pyscript</title>
<py-env>
        - numpy
        - matplotlib
        - pymysql
        - pandas
        
</py-env>
</head>

<body>
     <center><h3>Temperature mobile V0.0.6</h3></center>
  <div id="v_plot"></div> 
  <py-script  src="my_plot.py" output="v_plot">
        
     </py-script>
  <button id='id_plot'type="submit" pys-onClick = 'myplots'>Plot</button>
  <div id='rep'></div>
  <br>
  
</body>
</html>
```

my_plot.py file :

```
def myplots(*args, **kwargs) :
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
    figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=120)
    from js import call_servlet
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    console.log(f'args: {args}')
    console.log(f'kwargs: {kwargs}')
    snbplot = call_servlet()
    #console.log("réponse servlet :"+str(snbplot)) ;
    
    a_s = snbplot.split(';')
    x= np.fromstring(a_s[0],sep=",")
    y = np.fromstring(a_s[1],sep=",")
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.legend(["Temperature"], ncol=1, loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
    ax.scatter(y, x)
    fig
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Edit your question and show the entire code including HTML.

Comment: Resolved by using answer [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662125/displaying-a-image-using-pyiodide-and-js) Thanks to vikas-kumar-ojha

Comment: Either delete the question or post an answer that shows the solution. The solution is not obvious just by reading the link you added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying a image using pyiodide and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662125/displaying-a-image-using-pyiodide-and-js)